# How to get rid of button under button image?

Tags: html, css

What happens is before the button image loads, there is a button behind it and it's quite strange... How do I get rid of it?

```
<button id="cambtn" onclick="camera()"><img id="camicon" src="camera.png" alt="Camera" width="120" style="position:absolute; left:50px; top:50px;"></button>
```

Comment: do you have any css related to "cambtn"

Comment: Can you give additional information about this question.

Comment: @sheldonCooper nope i don't! only to the img "camicon" that is the button image.

Comment: Add style to button instead of img tag inside button. Set background image in css along with other styles

Answer (score 1):

If you put this snippet in your style sheet it should take care of the button formatting.

```
#cambtn {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Inline example (although not recommended):

```
<button style="background: transparent;border: 0 none;padding: 0;" id="cambtn" onclick="camera()"><img id="camicon" src="camera.png" alt="Camera" width="120" style="position:absolute; left:50px; top:50px;"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great :D Sorry my rep's not enough for me to upvote you yet!

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want a button, just don’t use the `button` element. Assuming that the element is not inside a form, just assign the click functionality to the image directly:

```
<img id="camicon" onclick="camera()" src="camera.png" ...>
```

Comment: I'm using some disabling with javascript after... I think I need the button function for that! (I think.. x.x)

Comment: @nomadie, you can easily remove the `onclick` property dynamically with JavaScript to disable the functionality, or to remove the entire `img` element.